# How to use learned word2vec in keras/tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network, word2vec, keras-layer

I want to classify 2 types of sentences: statements and questions. For this I need already learned word2vec NN to pass sentences throw it and receive 2d array for each sentence, e.g.:

[[~300 items], [~300 items], [~300 items], ...]

"300" is approximated length of word vector.

how to do that is keras? what library is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

What I adivce you is to use an [`Embedding`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) layer and set its weights:

```
input = Input(shape=(seq_len,))
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, 
    output_dim=300, weights=[your_w2v_matrix])(input)
...
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064690/using-pre-trained-word2vec-with-lstm-for-word-generation) you could find a really similiar question.

Comment: that quesion's answer refers to post http://ben.bolte.cc/blog/2016/keras-gensim-embeddings.html . but this post is incomprehensible

Comment: `Embedding` layer which was shown in my answer should also solve your problem.

Comment: can you show part of code, which transforms sentences to arrays of word2vec vectors?

Comment: Sure if you specify the format of your sentences and w2v matrix.

Comment: I don't have any format. simply, there are 2 arrays. first array contain statements, second - questions. I don't have even any train sample yet. so this is "abstract" sentences and in fact it is doesn't matter what in format it should be, I guess. and about w2v matrix. I don't actually know what is it. for me w2v transformation is black box trasformation. so, can you help me in this case?

Comment: In what format do these quesitions and statments are? Are they `numpy.array`s? Or lists of strings?

Comment: it is not important, but let's suppose that it is lists of strings, eg:
statements = ["some st 1", "some st 2", "some st 3", ...]
questions = ["some qw 1", "some qw 2", "some qw 3", ...]

Comment: I have the impression that the format of `keras.layers.Embedding` with `weights` is deprecated if you check this (https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) and this (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14392)