# How to interpret shape of word2vec weights?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, word2vec

I am trying to use the weights from my word2vec model as weights for the Embedding layer of my neural network in keras. The [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064690/using-pre-trained-word2vec-with-lstm-for-word-generation) that I'm following uses:

```
word_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, min_count=1, 
                                window=5, iter=100)
pretrained_weights = word_model.wv.syn0
keras_model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=emdedding_size, 
                weights=[pretrained_weights]))
```

I understand that word2vec creates vectors for each word, in this case of size 100.

`pretrained_weights.shape` returns (1350,100), but I am not sure what the 1350 number means.

`keras_model.predict(np.array([word_model.wv.vocab['test'].index]))` returns a vector of size 1350, which I am not sure how to interpret (the response the model was trained on is a vector of size 7200).

I can run the example code and get results fine, but I would like to know why it works.

Answer (score 3):

You already said the answer. Each word is embedded to fix vector of size 100. In your case, 1350 is the size of vocabulary, ie the number of words. At least that is what the `Embedding` layer expects. Each row of that matrix (1350, 100) corresponds to a single word. The `Embedding` layer simply does `weights[i]` for the given word index `i` and return the row.

When you predict, the output of your model, a single word it could be one of 1350 words in your vocabulary, hence you get a vector of size 1350 most likely a probability distribution from softmax telling which word it could be.

Comment: The text has over 3500 unique words though. Is it only making vectors for 1350 words?

Comment: Just realized I was looking at the wrong results. The text that model was trained on only has 1350 words, so this result makes sense.